# Problem with equation containing $\operatorname{lcm}$ and $\gcd$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$\newcommand{\lcm}{\operatorname{lcm}}$

I have a problem with this exercice:
Find all pairs $(x,y) \in \Bbb{N}^2$ as:

$$
\begin{cases}
        \lcm(x,y)=12\gcd(x,y) \\
        x+y=105
\end{cases}
$$

What I tried:

Let's put: $\gcd(x,y)=d$, $\lcm(x,y)=m$. Then: ($d\mid x$ and $d\mid y$) then $d\mid(x+y)$ which means $d\mid 105$. So $d \in \{1,3,5,7,15,21,35,45,105\}$, I have noticed also that $12\mid m$, but I have no idea what to do next, so please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By symmetry, you can take $y \ge x$.  Now as you say, $d\mid x, d\mid y$.  In fact, you need $x=3d,y=4d$ to get the $\operatorname{lcm}$ to work.  To see this, $12=\operatorname{lcm}(\frac xd,\frac yd)$.
So $x+y=7d=105, d=15, x=45,y=60$

Answer (score 0):

I would note that, if we write

$$
x = 2^{a_2}3^{a_3}5^{a_5} \cdots \qquad \qquad y = 2^{b_2}3^{b_3}5^{b_5} \cdots
$$

then, since $\gcd(x,y) = 2^{\min(a_2,b_2)}3^{\min(a_3,b_3)}\cdots$ and $\operatorname{lcm}(x,y) = 2^{\max(a_2,b_2)}3^{\max(a_3,b_3)}\cdots$ it follows that

$$
\max(a_2,b_2) - \min(a_2,b_2) = 2 \qquad \qquad \max(a_3,b_3) - \min(a_3,b_3) = 1
$$

hence either (WLOG) $x = 12y$ or $3x = 4y$. You can rule out the former case (as $x + y = {105}$), so it remains to check the other. We can write

$$
x + y = 105 \implies 3x + 3y = 315 \implies 7y = 315 \implies y = 45
$$

which implies that $x = 60$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't understand how you get $x=12y$ or $3x=4y$, could you clarify please?

Comment: Think of it this way: There is an extra two factors of 2 somewhere, and an extra factor of 3. (that's what the equation $\max(a_2,b_2)-\min(a_2,b_2) = {2}$ means, etc.). Either they are both on the same number, in which case we have $x = 12 y$ or $y = 12 x$, or they are split up between the two numbers, in which case we have ${3}x = 4y$ or ${4}x = 3y$.